# VBA Merging two or more totals based on user input, then delete the originals

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, merge, user-input

Hello Im very new to VBA and am currently working with this issue, im trying to merge two or more totals
based on user input as to the company name, example of the list:

```
2nd Cup        1937168

A & W          6485425

Applebee's     1550895

Arby's         8382549

Archie Burger    86776
```

The user needs to input the names of the companies they want to merge and this will create a new company with the total sum of the combinations, finally deleting the entries off the original list.

I currently am looking into an array for this but am not sure how it would work.

Any help would be vastly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a user-friendly approach, you can use a userform with an associated mult-select, multi-column  listbox (for the original data) and a textbox (for the new company name) and then write the code to process your data.

A good tutorial to get you started, from one of our SO experts, can be found [here](http://vba4all.com/two-column-listbox/)